# Cassandra conflict resolution during daylight savings time change

Tags: cassandra

How does Cassandra handle conflict resolution for updates
when there is a time change e.g. Daylight Savings time?
In other words, if a client goes back one hour will updates from it be rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamps used by Cassandra are (unless overridden manually) microseconds since the unix epoch (1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC). The timestamps are therefore not affected by daylight saving time changes.

Comment: If I manually set the clock one hour back on one client then updates do not get accepted from it.

Comment: OK, but that's not what DST changes should do.

Comment: Is there a way to force updates to go through and ignore timestamps? Let's say a clock was accidentally set wrong to a future date and then set back to the correct time.

Comment: There's no way to do that unfortunately.

Comment: Is there a way for a Java client to get feedback that the update got silently ignored?

Comment: No, because Cassandra can't tell that without doing a read and writes can't incur a read because that it too slow.

Comment: According to cassandra documentation an epoch is January 1 1970 at 00:00:00 GMT.- see http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html#working-with-timestamps